# Evaluating the pairwise euclidean distance between multi-dimensional inputs in TensorFlow

Tags: tensorflow, kernel, covariance, gaussian, tensor

I have two 2-D tensors of shape say m X d and n X d. What is the optimized(i.e. without for loops) or the tensorflow way of evaluating the pairwise euclidean distance between these two tensors so that I get an output tensor of shape m X n. I need it for creating the squared term of a Gaussian kernel for ultimately having a covariance matrix of size m x n.[image]

The equivalent unoptimized numpy code would look like this

```
difference_squared = np.zeros((x.shape[0], x_.shape[0]))
for row_iterator in range(difference_squared.shape[0]):
    for column_iterator in range(difference_squared.shape[1]):
        difference_squared[row_iterator, column_iterator] = np.sum(np.power(x[row_iterator]-x_[column_iterator], 2))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the answer by taking help from [here](https://www.reddit.com/r/tensorflow/comments/58tq6j/how_to_compute_pairwise_distance_between_points/). Assuming the two tensors are x1 and x2, and their dimensions are m X d and n X d, their pair-wise Euclidean distance is given by

```
tile_1 = tf.tile(tf.expand_dims(x1, 0), [n, 1, 1])
tile_2 = tf.tile(tf.expand_dims(x2, 1), [1, m, 1])
pairwise_euclidean_distance = tf.reduce_sum(tf.square(tf.subtract(tile_1, tile_2)), 2))
```

Comment: This uses O(nmd) space. The euclidean distance is more efficiently done using broadcasting rules and the identity ||x-y||^2 = ||x||^2 - 2x^T y + ||y||^2. This will use only O(nm) space and in my experience is much faster for large n and m